# Cleanup data in Allure TestOps

Tags: postgresql, allure

Is there any way to cleanup old report data from [Allure TestOps](https://qameta.io)?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't a build-in job schedular. You could install pgAgent, use a cron job, or whatever external piece of software

Comment: Create cron job - it not problem. 
Problem find data in database for delete

Comment: And how do you think we can solve that problem for you? We have never seen your database nor data.

Comment: Its DB from project allure, a lot of people work with this product.

Comment: There are all kinds of things called 'allure'.  If you can't describe what you are talking about, at least provide a link.

Comment: https://qameta.io this product

Answer (score 1):

Allure TestOps has a few different storages: PostgreSQL database for metadata and Blob Storage (S3 or filesystem) for attachments and raw results.

For Blob Storage cleanup you can follow the instructions from official docs: https://docs.qameta.io/allure-testops/briefly/project-settings/storage/

Automated database cleanup isn't available yet. But you have a few manual options:

1. Remove old launches one by one using UI
2. Remove old launches using SQL query `delete from launch where created_date < ?` (`created_date` is Unix timestamp in mills). All the related entities will be cascaded, so you should be fine.